# Redirect to https and sub dir on apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a bolt application installed and want to do 2 things with my .htacces: 
1st) Redirect to the `/public/` folder, since bolt displays an error otherwise.
2nd) Change all incoming requests to `https://`
Seperatly I get them to work, individually I get either: 404, installation error or missing files on the site since the path differs.
I now have the following that redirects to `/public/`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule cache/ - [F]
  # Some servers require the RewriteBase to be set. If so, set to the correct directory.
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.ch$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.ch$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [PT,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

In an attempt to switch to https:// I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L,QSA]
```

How can I solve it and **why** is this not working?